# How to display posts in all languages in the plugin Polylang?

Tags: wordpress, polylang

I am using the Polylang plugin and noticed that I cannot display a post simultaneously in all languages. that's why I wondered
is there a way to display posts from all languages on the site in a specific place
well, or create a separate language where posts from all languages of the site would be displayed

I have to do this so that it works separately from other versions -is -en
they would work as usual

but somewhere on the page [multilanguage news] or in versions -full
all posts created on different versions of the site would be displayed

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need something like:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'lang' => '', // no language specified
);

$posts = get_posts( $args );

if ( $posts ) {
    foreach ( $posts as $post ) :
        //do whatever
    endforeach; 
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

This would get you all the posts from all languages, you can add more args to the array if needed ...